# svn+ssh multiple users without having root access

Tags: ssh, svn

i have a svn repository on a server that i access through svn+ssh. 
i have only user access (not root) and i cannot install mod_dav.

is there a way to configure multiple user access (ie. with multiple ssh keys)
to the svn repository without giving the other svn users full ssh access ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just drop the extra keys into the authorized_keys with a forced command of `/usr/bin/svnserve -t` (or alternate path as appropriate).

Comment: thank you now i get it after to @christianwolff explanation. i didn't know you can force a command that way.

Answer (score 6):

What womble meant is that you can assign only one command to a ssh public key in the authorized_keys.

```
command="/usr/bin/svnserve -t" ssh-rsa ...
```

In this example the user accessing via his ssh key can only run the command `/usr/bin/svnserve -t`.

Comment: No problem. It's not a common task but it can be very useful as you can see. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to access subversion:

1. Via apache
2. svnserve
3. svnserve over SSH

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.html

If you've ruled out all of these then you need to move your subversion repository to somewhere else or not give people access.

Answer (score 0):

You can give each of the people you want to have access a public key which they can use to connect through the same SSH user. Forcing each key to only be able to run `svnserve -t --tunnel-user=<username>` gives each key a separate SVN identity. This is covered well in [a blog post by James Gardner](http://jimmyg.org/blog/2007/subversion-over-svnssh-on-debian.html).